# How to lock colouring groups among different plots in seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

My data frame has 2 numerical variables I would like to plot and 2 different categorical variables which stratify my dataset: *family* and *genus*.

I would like to do 2 scatterplots with those 2 aggrupations but keep the same colouring used in the *family* aggrupation.

I have tried the following, using the same `hue` in both plots, but the colours are not locked to be the same. Does anyone know how to insure they keep the same family colouring?

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(20,10))
sns.scatterplot(data=interaction_df[interaction_df['fam'].isin(d1)],x='gene_phage_length',y='gene_bacteria_length',hue='fam', ax=axs[0])
axs[0].legend(title='Top 10 Families',labels=legend_names)

sns.scatterplot(data=interaction_df[interaction_df['genus'].isin(q1)],x='gene_phage_length',y='gene_bacteria_length',hue='fam', ax=axs[1])
axs[1].legend(title='Top 10 Genus',labels=legend_g_names,loc='lower right')
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTKZ2.png

For example, in this picture *Salmonella* should be coloured blue like its *Enterobacteriae* family, not green.

And the data used as an example:

```
           genus            fam  gene_bacteria_length  gene_phage_length
0  Acinetobacter  Moraxellaceae             2642329.0            14142.0
1  Acinetobacter  Moraxellaceae             2642329.0            31509.0
2  Acinetobacter  Moraxellaceae             2642329.0            35025.0
3  Acinetobacter  Moraxellaceae             2642329.0            85755.0
```

Comment: Use a dictionary palette.

Comment: You can use `hue_order=` to fix an order on the hue values.  E.g. `hue_order=interaction_df['fram'].unique()`.

Comment: no hi ha que :-)